# google word tree chart last child fade away

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, charts, google-visualization

I implemented a word tree from this link [Google explicit word tree example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree#implicit-and-explicit-word-trees)

All the settings are same, on that link last child is not fading away, but in my implementation its fading away as shown in attached image.

[image]

As you can see "wk9" on top right corner, only half string is shown and also no tool tip popup as it does on others. Anything to pass in options? read documentation found nothing.

> When I set width to 3000 in options, complete tree is  loading, but
>   this will cause problem as width is always 3000 irrespective of chart,
>   any way to dynamically change the width would be helpful. I want the
>   chart  to overflow, only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a higher width. As you can see on this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pm9knypd/

if I set the width like this:

```
<div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 300px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

it fades away at the middle. Its part of the implementation. Just set a higher width

Comment: its filled up the screen and it fades, so no way to view more child nodes?

Comment: When I set width to 3000 in options, complete tree is  loading, but this will cause problem as width is always 3000 irrespective of chart, any way to dynamically change the width would be helpful

Comment: I didnt found a way to dynamically change the width. I would recommend you set the max width that you predict and handle the scroll bar with css or something. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: As we can see in the attached image, that map does not populate all the data when its size is less, I mean it just show 4 more..., 3 more..., where as if I give maximum size it will populate all the data. I want to achieve the maximum size which the chart require. It must take the size what it require not what I provide. i.e it should be dynamic in size. In future the size may increase hence I wanted to achieve that